# How to add a function on a column in a click event of syncfuison ejgrid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion grid in my angular js project where I want to place a click event to fire a function.

I have Tried the solution provided in this link https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/3767/how-to-place-hyperlink-in-grid-column

My HTML code snippet is

```
<div id="OverAllOverDueDoc" ej-grid e-datasource="OverAllOverDueDocList"
                 e-allowfiltering="true"  e-allowpaging ="true"
                 e-filtersettings-filterType="excel">
    <div e-columns>
        <div e-column e-field="CompanyName" e-headertext="Company" e-tooltip="Company" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="PlantName" e-headertext="Plant" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="" e-headertext="Candidate Id" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="EmployeeCode" e-headertext="Employee Code" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="BudgetCode" e-headertext="Budget Code" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="EmployeeName" e-headertext="Employee Name" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="EmployeeCategory" e-headertext="Emp Category" e-tooltip="Employee Category" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="Designation" e-headertext="Designation" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="DOJ" e-headertext="DOJ" e-width="80" e-tooltip="Date of Join"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="TotalOverDueMandatory" e-headertext="Mandtatory" e-tooltip="Mandatory Document" e-width="80"></div>
        <div e-column e-field="TotalOverDueOptional" e-headertext="Optional" e-tooltip="Optional Document" e-width="80"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

in the picture the highlighted two columns each cell will be clickable

[image]

Comment: Mixing jQuery with AngularJS like this is asking for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion Support.

**Query: I am using syncfusion grid in my angular js project where I want to place a click event to fire a function.**

We can achieve your requirement using the column template feature of ejGrid. And using create event of ejGrid bind the click event for the hyperlink column. Kindly refer the below code example,

```js
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="columnTemplate">
    <a href="https://www.syncfusion.com">{{:EmployeeID}}</a>
</script>

<script>

    function onGridCreate(args) {
        this.element.find(".e-gridcontent").on("click", "a", function (e) {
            alert("hit"); // do your stuff here.
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
  
<div ng-app="employeeView">
    <div ng-controller="GridCtrl">
        <div id="Grid" ej-grid e-datasource="data"
             e-allowfiltering="true" e-allowpaging="true"
             e-filtersettings-filterType="excel" e-create="onGridCreate">
            <div e-columns>
                <div e-column e-field="CustomerID" e-headertext="Company" e-tooltip="Company" e-width="80"></div>
                <div e-column e-field="ShipCity" e-headertext="Plant" e-width="80"></div>
                <div e-column e-headerText="Manage Records" e-template="#columnTemplate"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:
 [see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVzC5.png)

Kindly get back to us, if you need further assistance. We will be happy to assist you.

Regards,

Manivannan Padmanaban.